# strcmp refuses to work

Tags: c, strcmp, strncmp

I've tried everything, yet strcmp (as well as strncmp) always give a value other than 0, both with and without using pointers, as well as inside and outside functions. What should I do?

The point of the program is to create a student data system for signing up and in, as well as managing and sorting said data, the latter which I haven't implemented yet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int signup(char* ET, char* OT, int* G1T, int* G2T, int* G3T, int* avg, char* status, int* LI, int* sT, int* TT, char** UT, int** PT)
{
int i;
char LU[21];
int ID;
if (strcmp (status, "Register") == 0)
{
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", ET);
    printf("Enter first name: ");
    scanf("%s", OT);
    while(1)
    {

        printf("Enter C grade: ");
        scanf("%d", G1T);
        if (*G1T >= 0 && *G1T <= 10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {

        printf("Enter Java grade: ");
        scanf("%d", G2T);
        if (*G2T >= 0 && *G2T <= 10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while(1)
    {

        printf("Enter C++ grade :");
        scanf("%d", G3T);
        if (*G3T >= 0 && *G3T <= 10)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    *avg = (*G1T + *G2T + *G3T)/3;
    *UT[*TT] = *ET;
    *sT = 1;
}
    else
{
    printf("Enter username: ");
    scanf("%s", &LU);
    for (ID = 0; ID < 100; ID++)
    {
        if (strncmp(LU, UT[ID], 20) == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (ID == 100)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Enter password: ");
        scanf("%s", LU);

    }

}

return 0;
}




void pass(char** User, int** Pass, int* Total)
{
int cd[21];
int i, j;

for (i=0; i<21; i++)
{
    cd[i] = *User[i];
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        if(cd[i] >= 97 && cd[i <= 122])
        {
            cd[i] = cd[i] - 32;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(cd[i] >= 65 && cd[i] <= 90)
        {
            cd[i] = cd[i] + 32;
        }
    }

}


}
















int main(void) {

int i, j, z;
int succ, *sT;
char intro[9], *status;
int Total = 0;
int* TT;
int LoggedIn = 0;
int* LI;
char Ep[100][21], *ET, On[100][21], *OT;
int Age[100], *AgeT, Gr1[100], *G1T, Gr2[100], *G2T, Gr3[100], *G3T, avg[100], *avgT;
char UN[100][21], *UT[100];
int PW[100][21], *PT[100];


while(1)
{
    system("cls");
    if (succ = 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Last name found.");
    }
    succ = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Type your option (Login/Register): ");
        scanf("%s", intro);
        if ((strcmp (intro, "Login") == 0) || (strcmp (intro, "Register") == 0))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ((strcmp (intro, "Login") == 0) || (strcmp (intro, "Register") == 0))
    {
        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            UT[i] = &UN[i][0];
            PT[i] = &PW[i][0];
        }
        ET = &Ep[Total][0];
        OT = &On[Total][0];
        G1T = &Gr1[Total];
        G2T = &Gr2[Total];
        G3T = &Gr3[Total];
        avgT = &avg[Total];
        LI = &LoggedIn;
        status = &intro[0];
        sT = &succ;
        TT = &Total;
        signup(ET, OT, Gr1, Gr2, Gr3, avg, status, LI, sT, TT, UT, PT);
        for(i = 0; i<Total; i++)
        {
            if(strncmp(UN[Total], UN[i], 20) == 0)
            {
                succ = 0;
            }
        }
        if (succ == 1)
        {
        pass(UT, PT, TT);
        Total++;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

An example for my inputs is the following:

Register
LastName
FirstName
4
5
6

Then:

Register
LastName
FN2
7
6
5

And I expect to see "ERROR: Last name found." right above the starting message. However, it never appears, suggesting  strcmp failed.

Comment: Assume you're doing it wrong; `strcmp()` is totally reliable when used as intended.

Comment: There are several calls to `strcmp` and `strncmp` in this code.  Which one is giving you problems?  You should trim your question to a [mcve] that still illustrates the problem.

Comment: This is one of those "scanf is including a newline" problems, isn't it?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Run it in a debugger and make sure the strings you are comparing are what you think they are.

Comment: The one that includes newlines is `fgets`. `scanf`'s offence is that is doesn't treat newlines specially.

Comment: `i`, `j`, `z`, `LI`, `OT`, `On`, `Gr2`, `G2T`, ... "Great" variable names there.

Comment: Where is the code that prints the input value?  `printf("intro = [%s]\n", intro);` for example?  This would help you see what is being compared.  Is your input coming from a file or are you typing?  If it comes from a file, are you running on Linux but the file came from Windows?  Your `intro` variable is barely long enough; no room for error.

Comment: Actually, the site name may apply here.  All those local arrays in main() are eating up a sizeable chunk of memory.  Could be a stack overflow.

Comment: Please show us an example of input and the expected and actual ouput. And BTW the programming style is... let's say suboptimal.

Comment: Based on the recent edit, your issue is the second problem I addressed in my answer below.

Comment: *strcmp refuses to work*. This bold assertion made me LOL.

Comment: Start by writing a program that *just* reads your `intro` command (`"Login"` or `"Register"`) and make sure those comparisons work.  Then start adding back in more of your program logic.  That should help you find the actual error.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're allocating a lot of arrays in local variables in `main()`.  That could lead to a stack overflow.  You should probably use `malloc()` to allocate them instead.

Second, this line is an assignment, not a comparison, which is a bug:

```
if (succ = 0)
```

Change it to this, if you want it to be a comparison:

```
if (succ == 0)
```

Third, you're not initializing `succ` at the beginning of `main()` which is a bug.

If I see anything else suspect I'll update my answer.  But start with fixing those issues.

Comment: I don't think the many local arrays cause a problem, here it's far less than 100K and I doubt that any platform has a smaller stack than 100 K nowadays

Comment: @MichaelWalz - I work in the embedded world, where nothing has a stack anywhere near that size.  ;)

Comment: At uni, we haven't been taught to use malloc(), so I can't use that. Also, succ is always given 0 as a value right before the starting message is printed. While a stack overflow is possible, at this point, I can't think of an alternative solution.

Comment: @Tasos500 - Change (succ = 0) to (succ == 0).

Comment: @Tasos500 - And you are wrong.  The first time you run the while loop, succ is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code, as was pointed out, but the reason it doesn't work as you expect is the line: `if(succ = 0)`

I changed it to: `if(succ==0)`
And it worked as you described.

Additionally this line here: `scanf("%s", &LU);` should be `scanf("%s", LU);` 
The compiler is probably generating a warning about the format.

Comment: succ really was wrong. And as for scanf("%s", &LU); the compiler doesn't generate any warning strangely enough.

Comment: Interesting. What compiler are you using? gcc 5.4.0 is what I have that generated the warning.

Comment: I'm using Dev C++, which my uni recommended.